# Ignore onTouchEvent when StatusBar is pulled down

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

I am working on my app in fullscreen mode and I have hidden the status bar with the View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag. Showing the navigation bar works fine but whenever I pull down the status bar, the onTouchEvent method is called, which creates a really bad user experience because the method interprets the pulling down as a tap on the screen. Is there a flag/setting so I dont get a onTouchEvent call?
Thanks already

Comment: Any luck with the issue? I am having the same issue

Comment: Nope, I gave up on that since it is just a minor thing and you lose motivation after looking through the internet for hours for a soltuion